# Supersized Goto API onClick

Tags: javascript, api, supersized

I've been [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197577/how-to-write-a-javascript-function-to-load-an-explicit-supersized-slide) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038700/calling-function-of-a-jquery-plugin-supersized-via-its-api-as-part-of-a-cli) [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904154/how-do-i-use-this-api-of-supersized-jquery-plugin) on this issue but can't quite seem to find the right answer. Basically, I'd like for Supersized to load a different background image for each link at the menu on the top of my example [here](http://arijoseph.com/beta/). In other words, for each menu-item, I'd like to load a different background.

Here's my markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theme/supersized.shutter.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("body").addClass("has-js");
        $("form").bind("submit",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
        });
       $("#banner a").bind("click",function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
           $("html, body").stop().animate({
               scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
               scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
           }, 1200);
       });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({
                // Functionality
                    random: 1,
                    slide_interval:3000,
                    transition: 6,
                                    transition_speed        :   1000,

// Slideshow Images
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},  
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                                                                        ],                                          

                });

            });

            $("#newsletter").click(function(){ api.goTo(2); });                 

</script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>   
                        <a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>   
                        <a href="#directions">Directions &amp; Opening Hours</a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>   
                        <a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$('a[href="#newsletter"]').click(function(){
    api.goTo(2); 
});
```

to get the `<a href="#newsletter">` element.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this file helps you, its a little tutorial i made for make image loading (Change gallery images) with ajax/mysql/php with Supersized/Jquery

http://www.mediafire.com/?3hvw7ybic551w8b

Hope helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, you have to pass the image number you want to load

```
<a href="#" class="link_class01"><span>Menu Item 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="link_class02"><span>Menu Item 2</span></a>

$(".link_class01").click(function(){
api.goTo(1);
});
$(".link_class02").click(function(){
api.goTo(2);
});
```